# Why does request.get(url).json get a bad request but .text does not?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, bad-request

Writing some python to validate OAuth2 tokens using this link https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=

```
import requests

def verify(token):
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={auth_token}".format(auth_token = token)
    response = requests.get(url).text
    print(response)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    verify(2)
```

This returns the json below (which is correct) but in a String, due to the .text property. However if I use .json instead I get a 400 status code. Been a while since I've used python so apologies if I've missed something obvious.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

For the mean-time I've used the json library to load the string but just seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests


def verify(token):
    url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={token}"
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    verify(2)
```

[image]

you are using .json instead of .json() which is causing the issue.